# What is the difference between @Min/@Max validadtion in Controller and in Entity?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-validator

I'm creating a SpringBoot MVC Restful web service.
What is the difference between Controller's validation:

```
     Weather getWeather(
@PathVariable @Min(10) @Max(50) Integer temperature)
```

and Entity's validation:

```
public class Weather {    
    @Min(10)
    @Max(50)
    private final Integer temperature;
```

Or are its the same?

Answer (score 0):

there is no difference between them at all. the same meaning in both sides.

- if you put the validation in a function inside a controller that's mean the validation will be checked only when that function Runs. if an other function Runs and don't have validation of that attribute it will accepte any value because she didn't checked the validation.
  and for not repeating the same validation code in many functions. you can use validation annotation inside your entity and put other annotations like @valid... at any function you want it to check the validation constraints.

hope you understand what i want to tell you. and sorry for my english